# Swagger UI TypeError in Express with Typescript

Tags: typescript, express, swagger, swagger-ui

## TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

Whenever I go to this route(http://localhost:4001/api/4a7ed517 it'll open in my browser or any other http client like insomnia, but it's not working in the swagger UI.

All other routes are working properly except this one.

[image: Swagger UI Routes]

[image: Error]

Can anyone help?

I tried fetching the generated shorturl but it's giving me a error as i mentioned above.

### [Source Code](https://github.com/geekyharsh05/Url-Shortner)

```
const urlSchema = new Schema<IUrl>(
  {
    shortID: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    redirectURL: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    visitHistory: [{ timestamp: { type: Number } }],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

```json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "URL Shortener API",
    "description": "API for shortening URLs and retrieving analytics",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": {
      "name": "MIT",
      "url": "https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT"
    }
  },
  "paths": {
    "/api/generate": {
      "post": {
        "summary": "Generate Short URL",
        "description": "Generates a new short URL for the provided long URL.",
        "requestBody": {
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "url": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "The original long URL to be shortened."
                  }
                },
                "required": ["url"]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "responses": {
          "201": {
            "description": "Short URL generated successfully.",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "url": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "description": "The generated short URL."
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "tags": [
          "Short URL"
        ]
      }
    },
    "/api/{shortID}": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "Redirect to the original URL using the short ID",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "path",
            "name": "shortID",
            "required": true,
            "description": "The short ID associated with the URL",
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "302": {
            "description": "Redirect to the original URL"
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "Short ID not found"
          }
        },
        "tags": [
          "Redirect"
        ]
      }
    },
    "/api/analytics/{shortID}": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "Get Analytics for Short URL",
        "description": "Retrieves analytics data for a specific short URL, including visit history.",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "shortID",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "description": "Short identifier for the URL.",
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successfully retrieved analytics data.",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "redirectURL": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "description": "The short URL."
                    },
                    "url": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "description": "The original long URL."
                    },
                    "visitHistory": {
                      "type": "array",
                      "items": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                          "timestamp": {
                            "type": "integer",
                            "description": "Visit timestamp."
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "URL not found."
          }
        },
        "tags": [
          "Analytics"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the error message in the Console tab of the browser dev tools? On which host/port is the Swagger UI running - same as the API (`http://localhost:4001/....`) or different?

Comment: It's giving this in the console `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://github.com/geekyharsh05. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.` and the port is same.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 ambiguous endpoints defined.

`/api/generate`
`/api/{shortID}` // this can technically resolve to `/api/generate` because the `shortID` is *any* `string`

each of these endpoints can potentially be resolved to the same resource. You need to redefine these patterns to avoid any collision on your backend service.

Comment: If the backend is OpenAPI-compliant there's no ambiguity because the spec says `/apis/generate` should be matched first. https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.0#path-templating-matching

Comment: I have found this [Issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1569)